Weak-star closed condition
In Dunford-Schwartz,Linear Operator, I, General Theory, to prove the Eberlein-Smulian theorem we use the following fact:

Let $X$ be Banach space,
Let $B$ be the norm closed unite ball of $X^*$ and $x^{**}\in X^{**}$,
If $Kerx^{**}\cap B$ is weakly-* closed then $Kerx^{**}$ is weakly-* closed

I have some difficulties to prove this result. I think that Is usefull the Krein-Smulian theorem for which:
Thm Let $X$ be Banach space,
Let $C$ convex subset of $X^*$,
$C$ weakly-* closed iff $C\cap B$ weakly-* closed for all B balls

It follows immediately from krein smulian since kernel is a linear subspace

The linearity of the kernel permit us to say that if the intersection with unitary ball is weakly* closed then it's true for all the balls? If it's true, can you give me some hint to proof this?

Take a net $f_i$ in the intersection of the kernel and a ball of radius $r$. Assume that the net converges weak star to $f$. Then $f_i/r$ is in the intersection of the kernel and the unit ball and converges weak star to $f/r$
